# Swapping the dollar sign for a euro, American english keyboard

Tags: macos, keyboard

I know that the keyboard shortcut to use for the Euro symbol is <kbd>Option</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>2</kbd>. But I'm now using the `$` key, why can't I just re-assign or reprogram the <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>4</kbd> key combo to give me <kbd>€</kbd>?

Does anyone know a way this can be done?

Comment: UK keyboard € is opt/2, opt/shift/2 is ™

Comment: ... or did you actually mean American keyboard?

Comment: @Tetsujin If his normal shortcut is option shift 2, then he is using the US input source for English.

Comment: Yeah, eventually I figured that out - title says english keyboard... which is somewhat confusing if you **are** English, not American ;-)

Answer (score 3):

Two apps for remapping keys are Ukelele and Karabiner.

Also the Dutch keyboard layout is the same as US but has € at Option 2, if that is easier.

You can also set up a text replacement in system preferences/keyboard/text/replace with, so that for example $$ gives you €.

Answer (score 0):

One other possibilty for non-Apple apps like MS Office is to use autocorrect to replace the euro symbol with the dollar or vice versa...

Edit based on comments : many programs have an autocorrect function, this is from Excel :
[image]